# Need a transit visa travelling to South Africa via London

Tags: transit-visas, london, south-africa, barcelona

I have a NIE ID card from Spain where I live. Can I travel via London from Barcelona to South Africa without a transit visa?

Comment: Check here - https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Answer (score 1):

You can see the current rules for transiting the UK on the Gov website found here:

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/uk-visa-requirements-list-for-carriers

It is updated regularly so it is best to use the link rather than downloading the PDF.  This is a guide to help airlines understand the rules for transiting the UK.

Or you can also see here by answering a few questions if a visa is needed or the rules for transit without a visa depending on your specific circumstances:

https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Answer (score 0):

Your citizenship is not clear.

> a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area
> (EEA) country or Switzerland

Since you have a resident card for Spain, you don't need to take a transit visa.

Check by yourself here - https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa